# How are new sessions calculated on a mobile WAP website?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, tracking, session

On a 2G phone connection while surfing the mobile website if a user receives a  call, what happens to the page session? Does the session continue or is it considered to be the new session?

Comment: Who uses or cares about WAP? its donkey years old... nowadays no one uses WAP, its too old, too slow and not supported by 99.99999% of websites.

Comment: Assuming that it has been created and still in use, what would you recommend as the answer?

Comment: Depends on the manufacture and model of the mobile phone. If the mobile supports [WSP/B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Session_Protocol) then yes the session can be paused and resumed. Not all WAP phones are the same and vary dramaticly, a lot don't even support colour...